# Flutter: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart

Am a bit stuck and confused, I have this definition,

```
 Map<int, num> totalPerSection = new Map<int, int>();
```

and a call to it like

```
String getPercentage(int section) {
    log("getPercentage($section) called");

    num percent = 0;

    try {
      var secCurr = section;
      var total = totalPerSection[secCurr]!;
      log("getTotalPerSection($total) called");
      percent = (scores[secCurr] ?? 0 / total) * 100;
    } on NoSuchMethodError catch (_) { }
```

the strange thing am facing is that `var secCurr = section;` has a value but whenever I try to access the `secCurr` value on this line  `var total = totalPerSection[secCurr]!;`, this value returns back null. What am I missing it, or what am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated

Comment: your totalPerSection is a map with `<int,int>` type and down in the code section is just a single key i don't see the value of int type so because of it it gives value null ? you did not applied the key,value pair of the map correctly I think

Comment: checkout this var total = totalPerSection.containsKey(secCurr) ? totalPerSection[secCurr] : 0;

Comment: Where did you populate `totalPerSection`?

Comment: Check if the key "section" exists in your map "totalPerSection"